# NavBar screen Name and border bottom is change when screen is active in react js

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, styles, styled-components

I want Like this

[image]

NavBar.js

```
 <div className="icon-tab">
                <Link className='icon-name nav-link' to="/Feed">
                    <div className=''>
                        <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/1176/1176875.png" alt='FEED TAB' className='icon' width={27} height={27} />
                        <div className='icon-name'>FEED</div>
                    </div>
                </Link>
            </div>
```

App.css

```
.icon-tab {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.icon-tab:active{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0275b1;
}
.icon-name {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

 .icon-name:active {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0275B1;
}
```

when main active screen is home then homes screen never bar icon and home title colour will be changed and also bottom border is come when screen is open(active)

I am trying to do but it's not working my output is coming like this when my mouse click the icon and nearby bar title it colour change but after my mouse come down colour will be note stay in changes.

How to do like this when my home screen is open then my home screen never bar title  colour change , when my another screen is open then home screen never bar title colour is default black.

I don't know where is my mistake and how to do that

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

use NavBar instead of Link :

```
<NavLink className={'icon-name nav-link'} to="/Feed" >
      <div className="icon-tab">
          <div className=''>
            <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/1176/1176875.png" alt='FEED TAB' className='icon' width={27} height={27} />
            <div className={`icon-name`}>FEED</div>
          </div>
     </div>
  </NavLink>
```

In above codes when NavLink is active link get `active class` and change your css to :

```
.icon-name {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

 .icon-name.active ,
 .icon-name.active .icon-name
 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0275B1;
} 


.icon-name .icon-tab {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.icon-name.active .icon-tab{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0275b1;
}
```

Do you meant that?

Comment: No! not like this it's working the same as my code without NavLink but I want if my home screen is open then the home tab bar color also changes otherwise not change here you can see UI maybe you understand want I want https://www.figma.com/community/file/979273848820041488